# Do I have to removeObserver in KVO manually now?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I'm confused that do I have have to removeObserver in KVO manually now? When I search this question on the website, I found [Do I have to removeObserver in KVO manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514450/do-i-have-to-removeobserver-in-kvo-manually) this question. So I tried to add NSKVODeallocateBreak symbolic exception. But nothing happened when I set observer to `nil` without remove the observer manually. Then I tried watch the debug memory graph for `NSKeyValueObservationInfo`.

This screenshot is captured after adding an observer, and I try to update observed property's value for tests.

[image: adding an observer & test]

Then I remove the observer. It shows something in the memory disappeared.

[image: remove the observer]

Then I set the observer to nil. It seems nothing happened.

[image: set the observer to nil]

After that, I initialize the observer again, and add observer again. It shows something in the memory appeared again.

[image: initialize the observer again, and add observer again]

At last, I just set the observer to nil (without removeObserver). It seems same as the result with removeObserver.

[image: just set the observer to nil]

So, is there anything changed in KVO? Or my test is not correct?

My code is paste here: https://gist.github.com/kingcos/36575befa94a464d7aff689daa34f5d6

Comment: Try observing another object, not `self`.

Comment: You shouldn't guess, but read the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1408054-removeobserver?language=objc

Comment: Have you tried observing the memory leaks using Instruments does it produce the same leak?